# Pycharmでpsycopg2のコード補完が効かない

Tags: python3

Pycharm community Edition 201802を使用しています、

```
import psycopg2
self.conn = psycopg2.connect(dns)
self.cur = self.conn.cursor
```

`self.conn.cursor`の部分のコード補完が効かないので困っています。

psycopgは、pip installで以下をインストールしています。

```
Name: psycopg2-binary
Version: 2.7.5
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: http://initd.org/psycopg/
```

コード補完を正常に動作させる方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psycopg2のソースコードを[Github](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2)で確認すると、psycopg2.connectのメインの処理をしている部分は、処理速度を重視してC言語で書かれています。そのため、`self.conn.cursor`のコード補完をしようと思えば、C言語をコンパイルしたバイナリーを解析して関連するクラスの情報を取得する必要があります。現在のPycharmはそのような機能を持っていないと思うので、コード補完を動作させることはできないと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解できました。